# How to run Jest tests with a custom Parcel transformer?

Tags: jestjs, parcel

I have a custom Parcel transformer that transforms my import paths.

For example, `import "a/b/c"` actually does `import "./packages/a/src/b/c"`.

How can I run my Jest tests using Parcel?

I tried running `npx jest` but my imports do not resolve because Jest isn't using my Parcel transformer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) to let Jest know about your aliases?

Add this to your Jest config:

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^a\\/(.+)': '<rootDir>/packages/a/src/$1'
}
```